# Formula to detect and return text from the range?

Tags: excel-formula

I've been fighting with this for the last few hours. The problem is I have a range (in a column), which values are either "G", "A" or "R".

I have tried this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(AJ52:AJ75),"G")=COUNTA(AJ52:AJ75),"G",IF(COUNTIF(AJ52:AJ75,"R")=COUNTA(AJ2:AJ75),"R",IF(COUNTIF(AJ52:AJ75,"A")=COUNTA(AJ52:AJ75),"A","")))
```

However it does not work the way I need it.

So, if the column contains "G" values only, I need it to return "G", if however there is "A" amongst them, I need it to return "A" (regardless of the dominance of "G's" in the column), same goes for "R"; I need it to return "R" (regardless of the dominance of "G's" and "A's" in the column).

So, e.g. if I have: 10 "G" values and 1 value of "A" and 1 value of "R", it should return "R".

Thus:

```
"G" = when there are only G's in the column

"A" = when there are only G's and A's in the column

"R" = when R appears in the column, regardless of number of A's and G's (basically "R" wins over the number of G's and A's)
```

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Test for *r* **first**, etc.

Comment: So, I have rearranged the formula to look for "R" first, "A" second and "G" third. Unfortunately it's still the same.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Hi @Rob , I couldn't copy it cos the system to which I am connected in the virtual drive does not allow for that, hence the screenshot.

Comment: So you are unable to type it in yourself? Are you asking others to help you by hand typing it themselves for you?

Comment: You are violating Stack Overflow policy and rules which I linked to in moderator postings. I am helping you not get your question closed and deleted. I get no points for doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the tests is important.

If all the cells are filled and all the cells have one of the three values, then try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(AJ52:AJ75,"R")>0,"R",IF(COUNTIF(AJ52:AJ75,"A")>0,"A","G"))
```

We are just taking your three conditions *(at the bottom of your post)* and apply them from the bottom workinng upwards.

Comment: So, when I use it it comes up as "False" (all are G), when R is introduced to the table I get G, when one A is introduced to all G's, then I get False, when there is 10 G, 1 A, 1 R, then I get A.

Comment: PS. Not sure what impact it has but the R, A and G in this range are the result of the formulas and not simply pasted in values.